# Displaying html file using htmltools::tags$iframe in shiny is not working with renderUI()

Tags: html, iframe, shiny

This is my first question in StackOverflow. Please forgive me if the question is not represented in the proper format.
I have a saved html widget, generated using [flowmapblue.R](https://github.com/FlowmapBlue/flowmapblue.R) that I want to display in a Markdown Shiny Document.
I am using *htmltools::tags$iframe* to include the HTML file in the Shiny app. The file is kept under the *www directory*. For your kind reference, I am sharing the HTML file in the following [LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mv5v3c75lc5s97q/June_Spain.html?dl=0).
The code that is working and giving desired result is:

````
---
title: "Flow Map"
author: "xyz"
date: "8/14/2020"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r flowmap, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
    titlePanel("Mobility Flow Map")
    mainPanel (htmltools::tags$iframe(src ="June_Spain.html", seamless="seamless", height=600, width="100%"))
```
````

I am getting this result [Result without using renderUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBy8B.png).
But actually my Markdown Shiny document will be responsive where the user can select zones and desired months. Based on those names the relevant HTML file will be selected. That's why I need to use the next following code snippet:

````
---
title: "Flow Map"
author: "xyz"
date: "8/14/2020"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r flowmap, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
    
titlePanel("Mobility Flow Map")
    mainPanel(
                htmlOutput("display_map")
             )
    output$display_map <- renderUI({
        my_test <-  htmltools::tags$iframe(src="June_Spain.html", seamless="seamless", height=600, width="100%")
        my_test
      })
```
````

In this case the HTML File is not Found as shown in [Result using renderUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBsgu.png).
I checked few similar problems with renderUI() and htmlOutput() but I couldn't make out where it is going wrong. I desperately need your help in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Strange. As a workaround you can encode the HTML to a base64 string:

```
b64 <- base64enc::dataURI(file = "www/June_Spain.html", mime = "text/html")
output$display_map <- renderUI({
  htmltools::tags$iframe(src=b64,  height=600, width="100%")
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 
I performed some testing with your code and identified the problem is not with tags$iframe function. The problem is from jQuery AJAX call for the particular HTML files I am using from  flowmapblue.R. Warning message _[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience._
To cross-check, when I tried my previous code and your code with a simple _test.html_ in both cases it is working fine with tags$iframe. Now, I am trying to fix this issue. _base64enc_ is new learning. Thanks.